# "Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object" message in Chrome extension background script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Situation: I'm trying to create a chrome extension popup timer that continues to count down, even when the extension is closed.**

[The code for my project can be found here. The important files are Timer.js and background.js](https://github.com/ronlaniado/pomo)

I'm using ReactJS for my project, and I originally made the state change with a setInterval timer in my popup. I had everything working properly, but when I would close the timer with the expectation of it continuing to run, it didn't.

Then I learned that I had to use a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). 
I implemented it using a long-lived connection, posting messages back to the popup timer for every update I needed. I got the timer to once again work properly, but still, exiting the popup would "stop" the timer.

I checked the background script dev-tools, and discovered that the background script was, in fact, working properly, but the port to the timer component was lost since the popup closed, which makes sense. 
I get this error message: `extensions::messaging:102 Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at PortImpl.postMessage (extensions::messaging:102)
    at Port.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as postMessage] (extensions::utils:138:26)
    at setInterval (background.js:42)`

I understand what the problem is, but I'm now trying to figure out how to make the port's connection stay connected after the popup is closed, or if there's another way to fix my issue. If anyone knows a way that I can solve this issue, that'd be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The popup page exists only while shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there no way to "force" it to exist after it's closed? Is there any workaround you think I can do?

Comment: It can't exist when it's not shown. You'll have to solve the problem differently.